Python Tkinter use dataframe resulting from one function def (self,event) in different function within the same class
I have a combobox in one "subscreen" and I am filtering the original dataframe with combo box value but I can't use resulting dataframe to show it in the treeview function or else where. I don't know how to call this function to use it else where.
This is my subscreen:
class MantPrev(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.tabla_data()
        self.loc_combo()


    def loc_combo(self):
        conexion = CNX()
        CombValue1 = ComboLoc()
        calc_sinv = pd.DataFrame()
        sql = "  SELECT etc' "

        try:
            conexion.cursor.execute(sql)
            calc_sinv = conexion.cursor.fetchall()
            conexion.cerrar()
        except:
            
            col_name = ([desc[5] for desc in conexion.cursor.description])

        self.algo_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.algo_combo1 = ttk.Combobox(self, width=30)
        self.algo_combo1['values'] = ComboLoc()
        self.algo_combo1.set('')
        self.algo_combo1.place(x=50, y=40)  # grid(row=32, column=2, padx=0, pady=1)
        self.algo_combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.location)
        self.algo_combo1.delete("0", tk.END)


    def location(self, event):
        df1 = CL001()
        loc_selected = self.algo_combo1.get()
        self.df2 = df1[(df1.LOCATION == loc_selected)]
        return self.df2

    # I managed to print self.df2 but I can't manage to use it in a different function
    def tabla_data(self):

        self.Sele =  location()#####is not working# .to_numpy().tolist()
        
        self.tablaO = ttk.Treeview(self,
                                   columns=('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), height='20',
                                   selectmode=tk.NONE)
        self.tablaO.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=4)
        self.tablaO.place(width=1000, height=300)
        self.tablaO.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

        self.tablaO.heading('#0', text='Localización')
        self.tablaO.heading('#1', text='Descripción_MP')
        self.tablaO.heading('#2', text='Fecha_Estatus_OT')
        self.tablaO.heading('#3', text='Estatus_OT')
        self.tablaO.heading('#4', text='Elemento')

        self.tablaO.column('#0', width=140)
        self.tablaO.column('#1', width=140)
        self.tablaO.column('#2', width=140)
        self.tablaO.column('#3', width=140)
        self.tablaO.column('#4', width=140)

        self.tablaO.delete(*self.tablaO.get_children())  # Delete all times inside the treeview
        for p in self.Sele:
            self.tablaO.insert('', 0, text=p[3],
                               values=(p[11], p[1], p[2], p[13]))

        labl_1 = Label(self, text="Localización", width=24, font=("bold", 10))
        labl_1.place(x=50, y=10)

        labl_11 = Label(self, text="Elemento", width=24, font=("bold", 10))
        labl_11.place(x=300, y=10)

        labl_2 = Label(self, text="Fecha Inicio MP", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
        labl_2.place(x=550, y=10)

        labl_3 = Label(self, text="Fecha Fin MP", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
        labl_3.place(x=750, y=10)  # (x=ancho, y=altura )


if __name__ == "__main__":


To call a method from within the same class, you prefix it with self e.g.:
self.Sele = self.location()

because location is a method defined within your MantPrev class; self always refers to the class in which it is used. So when you call self.location() you're effectively saying "call the method named location that is defined in self (this class)".
Also, you don't really need self before df2 (honestly you don't need to declare df2 at all, as far as I can see - unless you're using it somewhere else in the class). It should be enough to simply return the data taken from df1
def location(self, _event=None):
    df1 = CL001()
    loc_selected = self.algo_combo1.get()
    return df1[(df1.LOCATION == loc_selected)]

This answer does a good job explaining when to use self vs. just using return

Thank you. First bit works but still I get error when calling self.location()

def location(self,event):
df1 = CL001()
loc_selected=self.algo_combo1.get()
return df1[(df1.LOCATION == loc_selected)]
def tabla_data(self):

    self.Sele =self.location().to_numpy().tolist()


self.Sele =self.location().to_numpy().tolist()
TypeError: location() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Ah, I missed that - you can simply update the definition of location to set a default for the unused event parameter, or replace event with *args (shorthand for "this method accepts any number of positional arguments") - I'll update the answer. FYI: event is passed in by this binding: self.algo_combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.location), but you aren't using it so it can be ignored/overridden safely.

Hi again JRiggles, if I get rid of event and self.algo_combo1.bind("<>", self.location) I get new error, saying the class hasn't got the attribute. I added the *args instead of event but then it throws error :

loc_selected=self.algo_combo1.get()
AttributeError: 'MantPrev' object has no attribute 'algo_combo1'

def location(self,*args):
df1 = CL001()
loc_selected=self.algo_combo1.get()
return df1[(df1.LOCATION == loc_selected)]
def tabla_data(self):

    self.Sele =self.location().to_numpy().tolist()

    self.tablaO = ttk.Treeview(self,


def location works but when trying to apply it to the def table it fails.

You don't need to remove the event binding here: self.algo_combo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.location) I was just saying that this is where the event parameter in location() comes from. Also, the reason for the AttributeError is because tabla_data() is calling location(), and  location() is calling self.algo_combo1.get() all before self.algo_combo1 is defined. You should be able to simply put the call to self.loc_combo() before (above) the call to self.tabla_data() in __init__ so algo_combo1 exists before tabla_data needs it.

Glad I could help!
